# Why is the next histogram not appearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, matplotlib-widget

I am plotting multiple histograms using buttons(prev, next). On clicking on next, the next histogram does not appear. However, the axes and the title appear.

I have tried using `plt.hist()`instead of `ax.hist()`, But then the buttons would disappear on clicking next.
So then to make the buttons appear, I tried including the button codes inside of the if:else statements.Although the buttons did appear then, I could not make them work from inside the statements.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsm')

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim(0, 100)
axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
ax.set_title("17 - Alpha OH PROGESTERONE - HORMONE ASSAYS" )
ax.hist(df.loc[0:1,'age':'age'].to_numpy(),4, rwidth=0.9)

class Index:
    data = df
    data_min = 0
    data_max = data.shape[1]-1
    selected = 0

    def next(self, event):
        global ax
        global fig

        if self.selected >=self.data_max:
            self.selected = self.data_max
            ax.set_title('Last sample reached. Cannot go forwards')
        else:  
            self.selected += 1

            if self.selected == 1:
                plt.clf()
                fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

                axes = plt.gca()
                axes.set_xlim(0, 100)
                axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
                axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
                axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
                ax.set_title("17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE")
                ax.hist(df.loc[2:6,'age':'age'].to_numpy(),4, rwidth=0.9)


            elif self.selected == 2:
                plt.clf()
                fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
                axes = plt.gca()
                axes.set_xlim(0, 100)
                axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
                axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
                axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
                ax.set_title("24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE")
                ax.hist(df.loc[7:17,'age':'age'].to_numpy(),4, rwidth=0.9)


    def prev(self, event):
        global ax
        global fig

        if self.selected >=self.data_max:
            self.selected = self.data_max
            ax.set_title('Last sample reached. Cannot go forwards')
        else:
            self.selected += 1

            if self.selected == 1:   
                plt.clf()
                fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)     
                axes = plt.gca()
                axes.set_xlim(0, 100)
                axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
                axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
                axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
                ax.set_title("17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE")
                ax.hist(df.loc[2:6,'age':'age'].to_numpy(),4, rwidth=0.9)

            elif self.selected == 2:
                plt.clf()
                fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
                axes = plt.gca()
                axes.set_xlim(0, 100)
                axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
                axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
                axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
                ax.set_title("24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE")
                ax.hist(df.loc[7:17,'age':'age'].to_numpy(),4, rwidth=0.9)

callback = Index()
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])

bnext = Button(axnext, '>')
bprev = Button(axprev, '<')

bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)

plt.show()
```

I expect the graphs to be a nice carousel. However, still waiting.

Comment: don't do `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` every time an event is trigger (`self.selected`), instead, do `ax.hist` which will render the histogram to the axis created by the first `subplots()` command.

Comment: @ Quang Hoang I incorporated the changes, However, The next graph now does not show?

Comment: Supposedly you forgot to redraw the canvas after changes are performed. `plt.draw()` or `plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()`